# AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'major_id'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I want to store all major id's that correspond to the school chosen in order to display only the schools corresponding to that major.

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import professor, School, Major, School_Major

def index(request):
    schools = School.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'locate/index.html', {'schools': schools})

#Original Attempt
#def Major(request, school_pk):
    #Filter to a show the association of 1 schools majors
    #school_choice = Major_School.objects.filter(school_id = school_pk)
    #Filter majors names required
    #majors = Major.objects.filter(id = school_choice.major_id)
    #return render(request, 'locate/major.html', {'majors' : majors})

#current Attempt
def Majors(request, school_pk):
    schools_majors_ids = []
    major_after_filter = []
    #Filter to a show the association of 1 schools majors
    school_choice = School_Major.objects.filter(school_id = school_pk)

    #Append each of the major id's to school_majors_ids list
    for store in school_choice.major_id:
        schools_majors_ids.append(school_choice.major_id)

    #Filter majors names required
    for store in schools_major_ids:
        major_after_filter = Major.objects.filter(id = schools_majors_id[store])

    return render(request, 'locate/major.html', {'major_after_filter' : major_after_filter})
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Major(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True)

class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True)
    school_Major_merge = models.ManyToManyField(Major, through='School_Major')

class School_Major(models.Model):
    major = models.ForeignKey(Major, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class professor(models.Model):
    ProfessorIDS = models.IntegerField()
    ProfessorName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ProfessorRating = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=4)
    NumberofRatings = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    #delete major from the model  
    school = models.ForeignKey(School , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    major = models.ForeignKey(Major , on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ProfessorName
```

url.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path(' <int:school_pk>/', views.Majors, name='Major')
]
```

index.html

```
      <ul>
        {% for list in schools %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'Major' list.id %}">{{list.name}}</a></li>
        <br><br>
        {%endfor%}
      </ul>
```

When the M2M relationship is established I have a seperate table in my DB which is called school_major (I'll show an image below of all the tables for visualization)

When I Chose a school, the pk of that school is suppose to query the m2m field (school_major) and essentially store all the major_id's, then query the major table and store the names of only the majors for that school.

Error message:

```
Internal Server Error: /locate/ 1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.2-py3.7.egg\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.2-py3.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.2-py3.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\David\Desktop\Actual_Project\school_finder\blog_project\locate\views.py", line 20, in Majors
    for store in school_choice.major_id:
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'major_id'
[16/Feb/2019 12:22:00] "GET /locate/%201/ HTTP/1.1" 500 68038
```

Below are the images of the tables, notice that there is in fact a major_id, and

**School DB Visual**

[image]

**school_major DB Visual**
[image]

**major DB Visual**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All those screenshots are irrelevant. You can't iterate over `school_choice.major_id`, that doesn't make any sense at all. You just need to iterate over `school_choice`.

```
for store in school_choice:
    schools_majors_ids.append(store.major_id)
```

(Note, there are still multiple issues with this code, both syntactic and functional. You should think more carefully about what you want to do, and read more about both basic Python loops and Django queries.)

Comment: And you append the element's `major_id`, not the queryset's, so it's `...append(store.major_id)`. Strange choice of variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so your error is because you do `school_choice.major_id` and `school_choice` is a `QuerySet` not an instance of your `School_Major` model which does have the `major_id` attribute.

So you'd want to do;

```
for school_major in school_choice:
    schools_majors_ids.append(school_major.major_id)
```

But if you're looking to get a list of the `major_id` the school choices you can do that a bit more efficiently;

```
def majors(request, school_pk):     
    schools_majors_ids = School_Major.objects.filter(
        school_id=school_pk
    ).values_list('major_id', flat=True)

    major_after_filter = Major.objects.filter(id__in=schools_majors_ids)
```

Comment: Well, even more efficient would be to just do `Major.objects.filtet(school__id=school_pk)`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yeah, good point. I didn't consider the structure that much, just followed the current logic.